# Adjusting the refresh rate of Firefox Live Bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Does anyone know how to adjust how often [Firefox Live Bookmarks](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Live_Bookmarks_-_Firefox) (a.k.a. Live Titles) refresh in the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change The Default Reloading Time of Firefox 3 Live Bookmarks Feature](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/07/13/change-the-default-reloading-time-of-firefox-3-live-bookmarks-feature/).

According to that article you will need to add a new entry,

> [browser.bookmarks.livemark_refresh_seconds](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.bookmarks.livemark_refresh_seconds)

to configure the refresh rate in seconds.
The default (without that entry in `about:config`) is 1 hour; that is 3600)

Do read the caveats at the [Mozillazine link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.bookmarks.livemark_refresh_seconds).