# Firefox Live Bookmarks - *LIVE* Bookmarks!

Tags: firefox, rss

Is there a way to make the *Live Bookmarks* actually be **Live** (as in, update every few seconds, rather than hours)? I'd like my page to show me new questions when I'm on Stack Exchange, without me constantly reloading.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it works on 3.6, but it should adapt and will refresh in seconds.

Here are two links:

- [Adjusting the refresh rate of Firefox Live Bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/43265/adjusting-the-refresh-rate-of-firefox-live-bookmarks/43269#43269)
- https://superuser.com/tags/refresh/hot

Comment: Thank you for the response! The first link didn't have what I was after (because of the caveats I was trying to avoid), but the second link did.